# Difference quantifiers of two same logic statement

Tags: math, logic, discrete-mathematics

I want to know the meaning of these two logical statement. These two statement is the same but share difference quantifiers. I try to google some examples on quantifiers but still not able to solve the question.

Statement 1:∀x∃y: If operation x is exposed by y, then y is a spy.

Statement 2:∀x∀y: If operation x is exposed by y, then y is a spy.

Can someone please give me some advices on these kind of question?

Thanks for your kindly attention.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about logic and [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Comment: In my defence, there is a valid tag with open questions and followers on this subjects. Logic should belongs to discrete mathematics which relative to computer science.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it is a little strange to apply the first statement to a conditional statement, but they mean:

Statement 1:∀x∃y: If operation x is exposed by y, then y is a spy.
For all x there exists a y for which it is true that if x is exposed by y, then y is a spy. The logic seems to be that there is at least one spying exposer out there (though note well with the quantifiers set up in this order it is entirely possible x is exposed by some non-spies as well). But why I am saying this is strange, is that logically, I could have a y that does not expose x, and that would satisfy the existence claim, because a false "if" implies any conclusion (i.e., if true, then false is true, and so is if false then true.).

Statement 2:∀x∀y: If operation x is exposed by y, then y is a spy. This says for all x, for all y (so basically for any x, y, pair) If x is exposed by y, then y is a spy.

Comment: I think that's the solution. Thanks a lot.